# Calling a function being "hidden" in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is such a function from a third-party library:

```
(function($) {
  window.NestedFormEvents = function() {
    this.addFields = $.proxy(this.addFields, this);
    this.removeFields = $.proxy(this.removeFields, this);
  };
//......
NestedFormEvents.prototype = {
    addFields: function(e) { .....
});
```

Is there any way to call `addFields()` from a client? `typeof window.NestedFormEvents` returns "`function`", but `window.NestedFormEvents.addFields` returns undefined as well as `window.NestedFormEvents.addFields()`.

The source code is here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_nested_form.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is constructor function. When called with `new` keyword it returns new object which has  methods defined in constructor's prototype:

```
var nestedFormEvent = new NestedFormEvents();
nestedFormEvent.addFields();
```

Now if you check `console.log(nestedFormEvent)` object you will see all necessary methods in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `addFields` as though it were a static method of `NestedFormEvents`.

Rather, it is a method of its prototype. So:

```
var instance = new NestedFormEvents;
alert(NestedFormEvents.addFields); //undefined
alert(instance.addFields); //finds function
```

In short, any time you're trying to use methods declared on a function's prototype, you need to instantiate it, with `new`.